# Why won't Ghostscript recognize my generated 'cidfmap' file?

Tags: ghostscript

(Using Ghostscript 9.27 on Windows 10)

I have no problem running the following Ghostscript command on my PDFs; the default 'cidfmap' file within Resources/Init is picked up just fine:

```
gswin64c.exe -I"C:/Program Files/gs/ghostscript-9.27/Resource/Init" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNODISPLAY -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dPDFSTOPONERROR -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

However, when I want to use a generated 'cidfmap' file (using the mkcidfm.ps script), it only wants to use the default, and will not use the generated 'cidfmap' file. The new command I am trying is:

```
gswin64c.exe -I"C:/Program Files/gs/ghostscript-9.27/Resource/Init" -sCIDFMAP="C:/Temp/cidfmap" "C:/Program Files/gs/ghostscript-9.27/lib/mkcidfm.ps" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNODISPLAY -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dPDFSTOPONERROR -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

I've tried adding "C:\Temp" to the list of directories in the -I parameter, but that didn't work.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is that there is no Ghostscript command line switch 'CIDFMAP'.

The way Ghostscript command line controls work is that any switch which is not recognised by either the interpreter or the device is assumed to be intended as a PostScript variable. Such variables are defined in systemdict, which makes them available to any PostScript programs whch might want to use them. Many of the utility program supplied with Ghostscript make use of this feature.

The only use for -sCIDFMAP is to pass a parameter to the mkcidfm.ps PostScript program, which tells that program the name of the output file to store the generated cidfmap in.

So what you need to do is generate the cidfmap in the Resource/Init directory, or copy it there, or tell Ghostscript to add the directory you are generating it in to the search path using -I. The most reliable method is going to be to put it in /Resource/Init.

I think (but this isn't my area) that Ghostscript will look for the **first** cidfmap file and use that, so if you put the resource files before the directory with your cidfmap in it then it will find them first. You could try swapping the search order, but personally I feel that's risky. If you are going to use resources from disk then just put the cidfmap in there.

Comment: Got it - I suppose that explains why I found the 'CIDFMAP' switch mentioned only once in the Ghostscript documentation. Thanks, Ken!